# Azure DevOps Server 2019 Analytics configure via Power BI query issue

Tags: azure-devops, odata, powerbi-desktop, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I get the following error when trying to configure via Power BI query.

DataSource.Error: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:
OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Details:
DataSourceKind=OData
DataSourcePath=http://boardpacdevops/BoardPAC%20Collection/BoardPAC%20UWP/_odata/v3.0-preview/TestPoints

**Azure DevOps Server Version** Dev17.M153.5

NOTE: All the queries related to Azure Pipelines and Azure Test Plans in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-odata-overview?view=azure-devops) happen to get the same error above. Azure Boards' related reports are working great.

Please let me know what am I doing incorrectly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's the result if you restart the OData service and test it again?

Comment: @ToBeOrNotToBe same error as above mentioned.

Comment: Have you checked if you've met all prerequisites [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/odataquery-connect?view=azure-devops#prerequisites). Is the account you signed in the basic role of the organization?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Thanks. I got the answer from dev community. I have added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from the [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/927870/view.html)

According to the description, we have checked and found that your mentioned article linked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-odata-overview?view=azure-devops, targets on Azure DevOps Cloud services, it provides 3 types of report, including “Azure Boards”, “Azure Pipelines” and “Azure Test Plans”.
Meanwhile, this article linked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-odata-overview?view=azure-devops-2019, targets on Azure DevOps Server 2019, it only provides “Azure Boards” related report. Please check it and kindly let us know the result.
BTW, if this other 2 kinds of the report are important to you, we recommend that you could submit a suggestion ticket to suggest this new feature in our User Voice linked here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22, then the product group will review your suggestion per to the vote count. Thanks for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing the solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.